# Import data from CSV into two tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, import, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a CSV import feature in my rails app. I have parents table and children table. Parent has many association with children. I am able to get the parent details from the CSV but I am not able to extract the children details.

parents_controller.rb

```
def import
    @parent = Parent.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to main_admin_path, flash: { success: "Parents Imported" }
end
```

parent.rb

```
has_many :children, dependent: :destroy

def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers:true) do |row|
        Parent.create! row.to_hash
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :parents do
    collection { post :import }
 resources :children        
end
```

main_admin.html.erb

```
 Import Parents
  <%= form_tag import_parents_path, multipart:true do %>
   <%= file_field_tag :file %>
   <%= submit_tag "Import"%>
  <% end %>
```

parent.csv

```
parent_1_firstname,parent_1_lastname,address,childfirstname,childlastname,childdateofbirth
John,Wilson,68 Bell Road,Jessica,Wilson,2002-11-11 
John,Wilson,68 Bell Road,Josh,Wilson,2006-10-01
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `find_or_create_by` method to create your parents.

Only after that, you should create the children. It goes like this:

```
# parent.rb
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers:true) do |row|
    parent = Parent.find_or_create_by(
      name: row["parent_1_firstname"] + row["parent_1_lastname"],
      address: row["address"],
      # ...
    )

    parent.children.find_or_create_by(
      name: row["childfirstname"] + row["childlastname"],
      birthday: row["childdateofbirth"],
      # ...
    )
  end
end
```

Note that you can also create children using `find_or_create_by` to avoid duplicates.

Comment: parent record is getting created twice. because of two children belonging to same parent. How can I get that fixed?

Comment: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n this is the other error I am getting

Comment: It should not create parents twice if you use find_or_create_by passing the same parameters. Do you have a children model and table with a parent_id field? If yes, you should also be able to create Child independently from Parent. Feel free to share more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

To not have to hard-code various nested loops doing find_or_create_by logic, there is a gem I've just released called **DutyFree** that makes imports and exports like this fairly painless.  It intelligently analyses the has_many and belongs_to associations on models and based on these relationships identifies how to properly save each imported row across multiple destination tables.  Either a create or an update is performed based on if the data already exists or not.

To demonstrate your example from above, I wrote an RSpec test with CSV data for John, Jessica, and Josh:
https://github.com/lorint/duty_free/blob/master/spec/models/parent_simple_spec.rb

More involved examples using the same Parent and Child models can be seen here:
https://github.com/lorint/duty_free/blob/master/spec/models/parent_complex_spec.rb

One nice thing about this gem is that after configuring the column definitions to do an import, you get export for free because everything works from the same template.  For the example using your CSV here's the template which allows the column names in the CSV to line up perfectly with the database columns:

```rb
IMPORT_TEMPLATE = {
  uniques: [:firstname, :children_firstname],
  required: [],
  all: [:firstname, :lastname, :address,
    { children: [:firstname, :lastname, :dateofbirth] }],
  as: {
        'parent_1_firstname' => 'Firstname',
        'parent_1_lastname' => 'Lastname',
        'address' => 'Address',
        'childfirstname' => 'Children Firstname',
        'childlastname' => 'Children Lastname',
        'childdateofbirth' => 'Children Dateofbirth'
      }
}.freeze
```

Add this into the Parent model and you're all ready to rock, and can call #df_import and #df_export.